# How to handle delayed events per group in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Spark watermark features comes handy when it comes to delayed events. But I am not sure how to handle a scenario where stream is generated from multiple devices in the field, and some devices my be reporting the events bit late. If we apply a watermark, eventTime watermark is maintained in spark against all events and not against the groupBy fields. So spark will drop all the events coming from the devices which are running(syncing) late. What is the best way to handle such scenario? I have modified the word count program from spark structured streaming to demonstrate the issue.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}



case class DeviceData(deviceId:String, value:Double, userId:String, timestamp:Timestamp)
object StructuredNetworkWordCountWindowed {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if (args.length < 3) {
      System.err.println("Usage: StructuredNetworkWordCountWindowed <hostname> <port>" +
        " <window duration in seconds> [<slide duration in seconds>]")
      System.exit(1)
    }

    val host = args(0)
    val port = args(1).toInt
    val windowSize = args(2).toInt
    val slideSize = if (args.length == 3) windowSize else args(3).toInt
    if (slideSize > windowSize) {
      System.err.println("<slide duration> must be less than or equal to <window duration>")
    }
    val windowDuration = s"$windowSize seconds"
    val slideDuration = s"$slideSize seconds"

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCountWindowed")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._


    // Create DataFrame representing the stream of input lines from connection to host:port
    val lines = spark.readStream
      .format("socket")
      .option("host", host)
      .option("port", port)
      .load()

    val deviceDF:DataFrame = lines.as[String].map(_.split(",")).
      map(value=>DeviceData(value(0), value(1).toDouble, value(2), new Timestamp(value(3).toLong))).toDF()


    // Group the data by window and deviceId and compute the count of each group
    val windowedCounts = deviceDF
      .withWatermark("timestamp", "2 minutes")
      .groupBy(window($"timestamp", windowDuration, slideDuration), $"deviceId")
      .count()

    val query = windowedCounts.writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("console")
      .option("truncate", "false")
      .start()

    query.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Here if device1 is syncing almost near real time, while device2 lag by 5 minutes, then the program will completely ignore the events from device2. Is there a way to apply the watermark against the groupBy function than keeping it as a whole?